# Update or insert into table depending if exists

Tags: mysql

I would like to update a table if the user is already set, if not I would like to insert the data into the table.

Now I am trying to do something with an IF statement, but that doesn't work.
as you can't start with an IF apperently.

this is what I have so far, maybe someone has an idea how to do this the right way.

```
IF (SELECT user_id FROM reports WHERE user_id=19) THEN
BEGIN
    UPDATE reports 
    SET latlng='42.12,4.124', facilities=null, organize=null, expired=null
    WHERE user_id=19
    AND id<>0;
END;
ELSE
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO reports 
    (user_id, latlng) 
    VALUES (19, '42.12,4.124');
END;
END IF;
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Can the person who down voted at least say why it got down voted so I can learn and do something about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "replace" keyword, see:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html

Comment: Thanks I see this is what I am looking for. Thanks!